# C# SerialPort Listening Port

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication

I am trying to do a serial communication between my micro processor and c# form application.

The problem is, data which comes from micro processor can come in 2 seconds or 5 seconds or 10 seconds. I mean there is no specific time and i would like to listen port and get data if it is come in 2 seconds if it is not, wait for the data until it comes.

I tried to this with serialport.readline(); but form hangs on while readline blocking, so i tried to do with backgroundworkers when i do this, i cant close form while backgroundworker is busy because readline command blocks the whole program.

All i am saying is, please give me some clue about listening the port while coming data time is not specific.

Thank you for your time (sorry for english it is not well)

Comment: Do you have any code sample you can show us?

Comment: trying to add new to stackoverflow

Comment: Inside your form close event, perhaps you could try calling `Close()` on the serial port as well. That should unblock the read call if you are using a `BackgroundWorker`, no?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SerialPort.DataReceived Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the data async. After you created an instance of the `SerialPort` class, you are able to add event handlers to the `SerialPort`. Thes event handlers are called if data was received.

```
mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
```

Inside the handler you can read the data from the input buffer and do what ever you want with it.

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    //Do what ever you want with the data
}
```

This is a very common solution to get data in unregular time steps which runs your application without blocking it.

Comment: but i dont get only one data for example, when i write A to serial port i get 400 data with a space between datas and data startswith "!" and ends with "\n" so i use arrays and if i write like you said arrays is not relaible.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: @oakar split the string by a space and you get  a string[] of 400 elements

Comment: I tried to post but site says it is not proper to add to question i dont know how to do

Comment: Yes i used split but read existing() is not good for me because while 400 coming, it is not waiting for whole datas

Comment: @oakar use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42976465/edit) button below your post to add information to your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) event. It will be fired everytime new data arrives at your port. You need to register to it like this:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort(/*your specification*/);
port.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;
```

In the event handler you would then read out the incoming data

```
private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort port = sender as SerialPort;

    if (port != null)
    {
        var incoming_message = port.ReadExisting();
    }
}
```

Now you just need to open the port and it will listen automatically. NOTE! the incoming data will arrive on a different thread than the main thread. So if you want to use controls of your form for display you need to use [BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx)

If your data is marked at the end with `\n` you could try using the `ReadLine` method:

```
var incoming_message = port.ReadLine();
```

Or you could try `ReadTo`

```
var incoming_message = port.ReadTo("\n");
```

**EDIT:**

If it is such a long time, than you should read it in batches. You could also try to handle it in a while loop.

```
private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort port = sender as SerialPort;

    string message = "";
    if (port != null)
    {

        while(port.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            message += port.ReadExisting();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // give the device time to send data
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you want to store the data declare a `List<string>` outside of the event handler and add the string when it is entirely read.

```
List<string> dataStorage = new List<string>();


private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort port = sender as SerialPort;

    string message = "";
    if (port != null)
    {

        while(port.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            message += port.ReadExisting();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // give the device time to send data
        }
        // add now the entire read string to the list
        dataStorage(message);
    }
}
```

Since the event handler does not know whether you have send `A` or `B` just collect the entire received messages in one list. You know the order in which you have send your commands, so later you can take out the corresponding message and use `Split` to get the 400 entries in an array:

```
string [] A_array_data = dataStorage[0].Split(" ");
```

Comment: I used this but Read.existing() not waiting for whole data for example when i write A to serial port i get 400 data with a space between datas and data startswith "!" and ends with "\n" so i use arrays and if i write like you said arrays is not relaible (i use split)

Comment: @oakar how long does it take for the device to transmit the 400 bytes? is it bytes? or 400 characters?

Comment: It is an electronic board, it has relays. When i say A to port, it reads the port and triggers the relay after that it measures the voltage and writes to the port and i display at c# form it take 3 seconds  i have to listen while relay do this

Comment: i have tried it blocks whole program thats why i use backgroundworker and then i cant close readline blocks program @Mong Zhu

Comment: @oakar what happens to the rest of the input after you have read the first batch with readexisting? does the event fire again?

Comment: @oakar you could also use a while loop and give the device time to send the data. I made an edit. Have a look

Comment: i write for example B and that is another 400 data after i write A. Also there are some datas which comes with space between them. Whole program gets almost 1500 datas when write something to port. The problem cant listen port properly. Can u give me an example like write port A wait for 5 datas it comes in 3 seconds if its not shows up give an error if its come write B and wait 3 datas and it comes in 10 second. Can u give me example like this? please. @Mong Zhu

Comment: I tried i can see 400 datas, but now the problem is, when i write A i get 400 datas, also B 400 datas and also C 400 datas. How can is put them in different arrays to store to use. is it possible with dataeventhandler @Mong Zhu

Comment: @oakar so did you manage with the while loop to read all the desired data?